# Error with webpack 4 and babel 7

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a project with React and Webpack as build system. My devDependencies

[devDependencies](https://pastebin.com/it5ND20W)

```
"webpack": "^4.5.0",
```

[webpack.config.js](https://pastebin.com/7dCn7Eaw)

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader'],
      },
...
```

And I get this error:

> ERROR in ./node_modules/project/components/InfiniteScroller.jsx
>   Module parse failed: Unexpected token (9:8) You may need an
>   appropriate loader to handle this file type.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're including uncompiled code from node_modules, your loader specifically excludes compiling node_modules code (`exclude: /node_modules/`) for efficiency reasons. Usually modules expose a compiled version of the library (usually in /dist, usually pointed to by "main" property in the package.json of the module).

If you want to parse code in node_modules, I recommend you just do it for `node_modules/project`, rather than all modules for efficiency. Modify your exclude statement accordingly, something like: `exclude: /node_modules(?!\/project)/`

You'll also need to make sure you use the necessary presets to handle the files (e.g. `babel-preset-env`, `babel-preset-react`) and any plugins the file might need (e.g. `transform-object-rest-spread` etc).

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have enough points to comment, I'll post as an answer -

I see you're importing a .jsx module - You should try adding

```
query: {
  presets: ['es2015','react']
}
```

to your rule after `use`